# How to use @DbLookups in different database

Tags: xpages

Ok this seems so silly but I'm having some trouble getting this to work.  I want to do an @DbColumn() or @DbLookup() to another database.  Same server - BUT it's in a folder.  And I can't get a result.  The view of the database in question is sorted by the first column.

I'm trying to populate choices of a combobox.

I've tried that built in @DbColumn():

```
var dbname = new Array("", "myfolder\\myDB.nsf");
return @DbColumn(dbname, "byCode", 0)
```

I've tried that with and without the "double slashes" and with column 0 and also column 1.

I've also tried the XSnippet : 
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=dblookup-dbcolumn-with-cache-sort-and-unique

That would be my preferred method really because of caching. I tried creating a SSJS function:

```
function getFacilityList() {
  var dbPath = database.getFilePath().split(database.getFileName())[0];
  return DbColumnArray("","myfolder\\myDB.nsf","cache", "sort", "byCode", 0)
}
```

Which I think should have worked but did not.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
    var dbname = session.getServerName() + "!!" + "myfolder\\myDB.nsf";
    return @DbColumn(dbname, "byCode", 0)
```

Comment: more like var dbname = [@DbName[0],"myfolder/myDB.nsf"];

Comment: All that is old is new again. The "BANG BANG" syntax is back. That was how you accessed databases on a server in Notes prior to version 2. It is also how the C API does it.

The key point here is that the JVM which renders the XPage needs to know the server or most accesses to databases other than the current one. This is especially true when running in the XPages in the Notes Client (XPinNC).