# DbColumn Lookup Code

Tags: xpages

I'm having trouble getting my @DbColumn to populate. I'm trying to use a drop down menu to display a list of departments, which is in a view called "DepartmentLookup" in an application that is called HCHPhoneBk.nsf.

I'm not getting an error message or anything, so that's not really helping me.

Here is the code I am using. The nsf file that I am working in, and the HCHPhoneBk nsf file are both on the same server, called DomTest01.

```
@DbColumn("aApplications\HCHPhoneBk.nsf", "DepartmentLookup", 2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the formula language (that is where this javascript code will be translated internally) the backslash is a special character. You need to mask it.

The first argument must be an array with the first element the server and the second the database. If it's the same database then you can use @DbName or blank array strings. A single value is only valid if it is blank.

Example:

```
var dbName = ["", "aApplications\\HCHPhoneBk.nsf"];
@DbColumn( dbName , "DepartmentLookup", 2);`
```

Alternatively try:

```
var dbName = ["", "aApplications/HCHPhoneBk.nsf"];
@DbColumn( dbName , "DepartmentLookup", 2);`
```

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030470/how-to-use-dblookups-in-different-database) for a similar thread

Comment: Merged my answer into yours and deleted mine.

Comment: most of this answer comes from you... Feel free to post YOUR answer and delete mine...

Comment: It's grand. :) You got yours in first. Sure it's only internet points anyway.

Comment: FYI: I edited this answer to use array literals instead of constructors; `new Array()` can have unintended side effects and its use is discouraged.

Comment: I had no idea I had to mask it. That worked perfectly, thanks guys!